# How to create a .d.ts type declaration file for existing JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, typescript, global-variables

I have an existing vanilla JavaScript library that is highly complex and I am writing a .d.ts type declaration file for it, but am having some difficulty.

I am fairly new to TypeScript, so am not familiar with its restrictions or limitations. I started my types file as a .ts file that I included in a project that was using this JavaScript library, and it worked just fine there. The library defines a number of global variables, so I have a `declare global` block to define those, so I can refer to them without having to import them.

When I try to migrate the declaration file to the JavaScript library as a .d.ts file (and I added "types": "./types.d.ts" to its package.json), I don't get any of the types when I include the library in another project. When comparing what I have to an existing npm module, I don't see any example of `declare global`, but I did note the use of `declare module` and thought maybe I need to use that. But when I tried that, TypeScript complains about my `declare global` statement at the end. If I put it outside the declare module block, it complains about `Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.` If I put it inside the module block, it complains about `A 'declare' modifier cannot be used in an already ambient context.`

What is the correct way to define a .d.ts file for a vanilla JavaScript package, that defines some global variables, so that the types can be consumed when the package is used in a TypeScript project?

Comment: If you are the author of the library then all you have to do is add `.d.ts` files in the same directory as the `.js` files. Eg if you have `index.js` then create `index.d.ts` next to it. In `.d.ts` you do not need to have `declare global` or `declare module`, just `declare const` for variables and `declare function` for functions etc.

Comment: I'm creating a type declaration file for an existing vanilla JavaScript library (npm package). The package.json specifies "main": "main.js". I tried as you suggested to create a main.d.ts file and declare the globals, but still it does not work. VSCode does not recognize the declarations when I edit a file in a project that includes this library.

Comment: Can you show the examples of what you tried? Maybe you made a mistake somewhere. For third party packages the `declare module 'pkg-name' {...}` should work and you should not use `declare global` inside of `declare module`.

Comment: If I use declare module 'name', then don't I have to refer to anything defined within there as name.property? The library I am typing provides a number of globals that I want to be able to address directly. The declarations file I created worked just fine when I included it in the project that was consuming the library, but I want it in the library so that any project that wants to consume it can use it. I don't understand why the syntax is different.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples to get you going with a list of solutions to common problems.

---

First for global variables you use `declare global` without specifying the module:

```
declare global {
    type MyType = string | number

    class MyClass {
        getData(): string
    }
}

export {} // you need to have an export statement, even if you are not exporting anything
```

TypeScript ignores files that have no exports (it doesn't think it's a module), hence why I had to add that empty export statement in the example.
If you are creating types for the first time you may have gotten stuck because of this.
This is likely why you had the error that you mentioned.
You do not need to have the empty export `export {}` if you actually have real exports, so you may not have seen this in other examples.

Another common problem is in `tsconfig.json`.
By default TypeScript will look at all files in your project, but if you specified "files" or "include" in tsconfig then TypeScript will only look at those files and ignore everything else.
That can be simply solved by including the file(s) with your global definitions:

```json
{
  "include": [
    "global.d.ts",
    "../path/to/more-global.d.ts"
  ],
}
```

When installing a package with global types as a dependency under `node_modules` there are 2 cases:

- If the package is under `node_modules/@types/` then it is always included,
  even if you specified `"exclude": ["node_modules"]`
- For all other packages you have to explicitly include them
  `"include": ["node_modules/example"]`
  Even if you have `"include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]` that is not enough
  you will have to add the package explicitly:
  `"include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "node_modules/example"]`
  And you can't have `"exclude": ["node_modules"]`
  because that would conflict with the "include" rule.
  In general you don't need to use "exclude" if you are using "include".

If you are writing types for an existing js library then you should make a pull request [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), so that the types could be placed under `@types/`

Note: Since we used `declare global` TypeScript will not know which module it belongs to. It will simply assume it is imported somewhere. So it can not warn you if you forget to import the module that actually creates those global variables.

---

For module exports the declarations are fairly similar:

```
declare module 'example' {
    type MyType = string | number

    class MyClass {
        getData(): string
    }
}
```

Everything inside `declare module` is exported implicitly, so we did not need to worry about adding a dummy export like in the earlier example.

You still have to update `tsconfig.json` to include this file, same as you did for global declarations.

If you want to write declarations for a sub-module the syntax would be:

```
declare module 'example/path/to/file' {}
```

Comment: I assume the tsconfig.json is for the project that uses the library, since the library does not use TypeScript. I didn't need to specify anything when I put the declaration file in the project itself, as tsconfig.json specifies "include": ["\*\*/*.ts", "\*\*/*.tsx"],
But the tsconfig.json also specifies  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
Is this going to prevent me from picking up the .d.ts file from the library? From everything I've read, I got the impression you didn't need to specify it explicitly. There are exports in the file, and I can't specify declare global and module in the same file.

Comment: @user1588877 It depends. I made an edit to explain everything you'll need to consider.